# Как перевернуть popup в menu на 180 градусов

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="Строка 1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:title="Строка 2"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:title="Строка 3"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:title="Строка 4"/>
    </menu>
```

1. У меня имеется popup menu, оно всплывает при нажатии на кнопку, по умолчанию popup menu ориентировано вертикально, а мне нужно перевернуть его на 180 градусов, чтобы оно было верх ногами.
   Я пробовал дописать к `item` вот такой код `android:rotation="180"`
2. А еще popup меню появляется не из того места, где находится кнопка а всегда в правом углу, можно ли как нибудь самостоятельно указать место появления popup menu?

Comment: а зачем вам такой прием? Т.е. буквы прям к верх ногами должны быть?

Comment: Во-первых, не понятно, у Вас таки получилось повернуть PopupMenu? А насчет появления в углу, вам необходимо назначить view, к которой popup принадлежит

Comment: popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.timeout_menu, <И вот тут как раз та самая view, к которой ее нужно прицепить>)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев Да, мне нужно, чтобы буквы были верх ногами.

Comment: могу сказать вам одно: средствами анимации нельзя зафиксировать результат. Вам нужен иной подход (если он есть, т.к. задача не регулярная)